# How to write YARA rules based on IOC script?

Tags: python, rules, malware

can anyone help to convert a small portion of IOC script into YARA rules for identifying malware?

I will try to learn how to write YARA rules based on the example that anyone has written for me.

This is a small part of the IOC script:

```
<IndicatorItem id="50455b63-35bf-4efa-9f06-aeba2980f80a" condition="contains">
<Context document="ProcessItem" search="ProcessItem/name" type="mir"/>
<Content type="string">winlogon.exe</Content>
</IndicatorItem>

<IndicatorItem id="b05d9b40-0528-461f-9721-e31d5651abdc" condition="contains">
<Context document="ProcessItem" search="ProcessItem/HandleList/Handle/Type"         type="mir"/><Content type="string">File</Content>
</IndicatorItem>
```

Can anyone also explain to me how to convert this to YARA and can I use Python to do that? THANKS ALOT!!

Answer (score 2):

From the information shown in that IOC script snippet you can not create a YARA rule. YARA rules are based on file content, so, you must look for indicators related to file content, like this one:

```
<IndicatorItem id="09cd0494-702c-4fe2-bbd4-29538cb3b685" condition="contains">
        <Context document="FileItem" search="FileItem/StringList/string" type="mir" />
        <Content type="string">http://%s/record.asp?device_t=%s</Content>
        <Comment>unique strings found in most samples in family</Comment>
</IndicatorItem>
```

This indicator is telling you that infected files contain the string `http://%s/record.asp?device_t=%s`. The same idea expressed in YARA looks like:

```
rule <a name for your rule here> {
  strings:
     $a = "http://%s/record.asp?device_t=%s"
  condition:
     $a
}
```

Here you have a tool which automatically does IOC to YARA translation:

https://github.com/mandiant/ioc_writer/tree/master/examples/openioc_to_yara

And here some slides that could be useful for you also:

https://media.blackhat.com/us-13/Arsenal/us-13-Gibb-IOCWriter_11-Slides.pdf